# Number of reflections required to map $n$ points into $n$ points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If we have $P_1,...,P_n$, and $Q_1,...,Q_n$ points in an euclidian space such that $ d(P_i,P_j) = d(Q_i,Q_j)$, its easy to show that using up to $n$ reflections, we can map each $P_i$ into $Q_i$. The proof is constructive. We use the reflection $R_i$ to send $P_i$ into $Q_i$ and show that all the previous points ($P_1, ..., P_{i-1}$) stay fixed. I have two questions about this method:

-Does the order of the points affect the total number of reflections?

-Does this method uses the least amount of reflections required?

Comment: By Euclidean space, do you mean 2-D, 3-D, or $n-D$? In particular, how do you keep all of the previous points fixed?

Comment: 1/ the order of points affect the parity of reflections (which reverse orientation). 2/ I suspect that we need 1 or 2 reflections (corresponding to orientation). The $2-D$ case is easy/obvious, and I've not through through the higher dimensions.